# Cleanup the [typing] tag

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request

[typing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/typing) is a pretty mixed bag:

- how to enter specific characters
- keyboard hardware problems
- how to change font attributes in various software
- hot to handle various page layout and LaTeX problems
- issues with hotkeys
- how to use or accomplish tasks on data entry devices
- handling foreign languages
- typing methods and ergonomics
- auto-completion
- learning aids
- etc.

A number of these usages would benefit from a tag but a catch-all tag doesn't seem valuable.  This isn't my area, so specific recommendations ought to come from people for whom the tags are relevant.  I'll just put this out there and people can suggest the best resolutions in answers.

Comment: There's already [keyboard] and specific-brand keyboard tags for keyboard technical support/foreign languages/hotkeys, so those should be tagged  with those. I feel ergonomics and methods/learning could have a [typing-ergonomics] and [typing-technique] respectively, but I'm not overly worried if we don't.